# How to access resources from other assembly

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource

I have an assembly which is used by multiple other projects. One task of this assembly is to display an image. The images are stored as embedded resources in the other projects. I'd like to centralize the logic of fetching them from the assembly.

This code works fine from the application which contains the resource. From the library it returns `null`:

```
var myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var result = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(ResourceName);
```

It seems the resources are scoped per assembly. Is there a way to

Answer (score 0):

Problem fetched the wrong assembly. With the following snippet I got the right content:

```
var myAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
var result = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(ResourceName);
```